# Как сделать такой эффект появления?

Tags: css

Каким образом можно через анимации сделать такое появления блока
Я сделал через @keframes таким образом

```
@keyframes sliderv{
  0% {
    transform: translate(-150px, 80px)
  }
  33.3333333% {
    transform: translate(-75px, 0px)
    }

  66.6666666% {
    transform: translate(-35px, -20px)
    }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0,0)}

  }

.others-wrapper.active
  .slick-slide.slick-active
    animation-name: sliderv 
    animation-duration 1s
```

Но к сожалению анимация идет с фризами
Идея такая что бы был плавный эффект волны)
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Вот тут гляньте, может заберете что-то, подходящее вам: https://codepen.io/search/pens?q=wave

Comment: Искал по wave но там другие варианты показывают